# Auto Increment id In Django SQLIite Database

Tags: python, django, database

I have set a field image_id as auto increment. But the issue comes when lets say:
I enter an image in the database from the django admin panel, it is assigned an auto inc id 1. Then I delete the same image. And then when I insert a new image its ID gets assigned as 2, why isn't it getting assigned as 1? As I have deleted the image with id 1, so technically id 1 is empty and it should be assigned to next incoming image. Can you suggest its solution please.

(Updated requirement):  Is there any way I can get the min assigned id and max assigned id. I am passing this range to a function that is generating a random number. So how can I get the minimum assigned Id and max assigned one

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind showing us what you've tried so far?

Comment: That is how primary keys work it always increment the value. It is not specific to sqlite any database does it. The deleted id will not be reused. That is how clustered indices are implemented. You need to define a separate column for that.

Comment: @Ahtisham Thank you buddy for adding to my knowledge. Is there any way I can get the min assigned id and max assigned id. I am passing this range to a function that is generating a random number. So how can I get the minimum assigned Id and max assigned one

Comment: Update the question with your requirement.

Comment: Why you want min and max assigned id ? I don't get the logic ? And what is the purpose of function that generates random number ?

Comment: @Ahtisham 
def home(request):
    image_id1 = random.randint(9,12)
    image = P_Images.objects.filter(image_id=image_id1)
    context = {'image':image}
    return render(request, 'photos/home.html', context)

I am using random number to implement the functionality that whenever someone visits the site, a random new image is displayed. I used various methods but this one worked for me

Comment: @OsamaMustafa Update that with your question

Answer (score 1):

> And then when I insert a new image its ID gets assigned as 2, why
> isn't it getting assigned as 1?

That is how primary keys work it always increment the value. It is not specific to SQLite any database does it. The deleted id will not be reused.

To generate a random image every time you can do it like this:

```
import random

def your_view(request):
  count_images = Image.objects.count()
  img = random.randint(0, count_images)
  random_image = Image.objects.all()[img]
  # show your random image
```

Comment: @OsamaMustafa if this fixed your issue please mark the answer as accepted and if you think this would valuable for future readers then upvote too.